# Grep inside /sys file returns nothing

Tags: grep, sysfs

I want to search for a string inside the `/sys/class/tty/*` directories. So I tried with:

```
# grep -rn path -e pattern
```

but it returns nothing. Example:

```
# cat /sys/class/tty/ttySTM0/iomem_base 
0x40010000

# ls -l /sys/class/tty/ttySTM0/iomem_base 
-r--r----- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 10:37 /sys/class/tty/ttySTM0/iomem_base

# grep -rn /sys/class/tty/ -e 0x40010000
#
```

If I use the same syntax inside another directory it seems to work:

```
# grep -rn /opt -e Could
# /opt/logs/joku1_log.txt:29:Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
```

Is there some caveats for such a research?
My goal is to find which `tty` has a specific `iomem_base` address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use either of these instead:

```
grep -rn /sys/class/tty/* -e 0x40010000 2> /dev/null

grep -Rn /sys/class/tty/ -e 0x40010000 2> /dev/null
```

The glob in the first command is needed in order to have it follow the symlinks that aren't specified on the command line as the contents of `/sys/class/tty` are all symlinks to the contents of `/sys/devices/virtual/tty` and `/sys/devices/platform/serial####/tty`.

The `-R` in the second command follows the symlinks by default with no glob being needed.

I added `2> /dev/null` to send the `Input/output error` and `Permission denied` messages to `/dev/null` as the output is easier to read when all of that isn't returned.

Answer (score 6):

The entries in `/sys/class/tty` are symbolic links to directories into a different part of `/sys` which is organized according to how the devices are connected internally. `grep -r` doesn't follow symbolic link to directories.

`grep -R` follows symbolic links, but it's a bad idea to follow directories when traversing `/sys` recursively because there are infinite loops (`/sys/foo/bar` is a link to `/sys/corge/wibble` which links to `/sys/foo`).

So specify the paths more precisely. This is enough to search in all the files of all tty devices:

```
grep -l -r -x 0x40010000 /sys/class/tty/*/
```

By the way, since you already know the whole contents of the file and want the file name, `-n` is useless and `-l` gives you uncluttered output. `-x` helps to avoid false positives (but it isn't necessary here since the content of `iomem_base` has fixed length).

But since you know the file's base name, just search that one.

```
grep -l -x 0x40010000 /sys/class/tty/*/iomem_base
```

Comment: Thanks. I was fooled by the sym links because they are set on *directories*... instead I checked on *files*.